# How to create two Joomla community builder(CB) registration forms

Tags: joomla, joomla-community-builder

I have  Joomla 3.x  website . I am using CB(community builder) for user registration and log in.
     I want to have another registration form on another page with some different field.
   I have a already registration page here http://urbanaccessregulations.eu/register/registers.  I need an other registration form on another page(http://urbanaccessregulations.eu/stakeholer-login).
    I  need basically two different registration form for two different pages.
        Is this possible by community builder .
    Please suggest me how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with [Profile Pro](http://www.joomduck.com/extensions/community-builder-profile-pro) plugin for Community Builder. It allows to create separate registration forms with different fields and even multi-step registrations.